# Phonegap app can't install from Google play

Tags: android, cordova

When I install my apk directly on my device it will install and run. 
When I download it from Google Play it will result in:

Unknown Error code during application install: "-24"

Even on devices the app hasn't been installed before.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your /data/data/ folder and search for your com.foobar.myapp
Delete it, install the application again. It may work, but the causes or this error code are multiple.

Comment: Yeah, I saw these answers too. But it also gets -24 on devices the app hasn't been on before. Search for Photo Flirt in Google Play.